# How to find count that how many times a product is sold in each category?

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to get the number of times a certain product is sold or ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the product sold count from below table.

For magento 1.x refer "sales_flat_order_item"
For magento 2.x refer "sales_order_item"